# How to set bash default shell for the root user

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, zsh

my shell config was changed to zsh for the root user for some reason. This does not allow me to root user and I do not have another user in sudoers file, can I return the shell configuration to bash without having root access or a user in sudoers file? this on a ubuntu server

Comment: You can't change settings for the `root` user without having root access. How did you even learned the root shell was changed if you can't login as `root`?

Comment: What does _"This does not allow me to root user"_ mean exactly? What's the actual problem?

Answer (score 1):

One can run `cat /etc/shells` to see the full path of available shells on the system.

You can use [chsh](https://linux.die.net/man/1/chsh) (“change shell” ) command to change your default shell.

`chsh -s {shell-name-here} {user-name-here}`

As a normal user, you may only change the login shell for your own account. That might also not be possible if you are currently in restricted shell, which doesn't seem to be the case for you.

Comment: `chsh` is the right tool to change a user's shell, the problem is that it's root's shell that needs changing.  So this, combined with `su -s /bin/bash` is a good answer (but note that `su` requires the OP to know what the root password is.  If it's not known or if there is no root password, then they will have to boot to rescue mode or with a rescue CD/USB/etc).